# tmux on Mac, how can I enable vi mode for the command line

Tags: bash, vi

I want to be able to hit escape and then use vi navigation keys like b (back a word). I can do this in my regular terminal sessions by setting `set -o vi` in my .bashrc file.

However it's not working in tmux. I added `set -o vi` in my .tmux_conf file, but it only works for 1 "hit" then I get switched back into insert mode after hitting the key.  So if I press [escape] i can go back one word with [b] but then the next [b] just inserts the `b` character.

How can I make that 'vi' mode work in my tmux sessions the same way it does at my 'plain' bash shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `set -o vi` to the `~/.bash_profile` file